# Tab key is not working as expected

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have [this form](http://%20http://tulipindia.biz/associate_form.php), and the problem is the sequence of tab is not working correctly

If you visit the site you will find that after pressing the tab key after the date of birth calender field the  sequence of the tab key gets  disappeared. After preesing the tab key in keyboard after the Date of birth field the focus is not going to the next field i.e Occupation: *. Instead it gets diappeared

How can this be solved?

Comment: *"Please dont downvote the question"* Clearly you anticipated being down voted. Maybe you should consider why that is, and structure your question so that people won't want to down vote it.

Comment: Code dumps like that are NOT useful.

Comment: The main reason i had written "Please dont downvote the question" is that if i get downvote then i am restricted for further asking question

Comment: @Somdebmukherjee: So you have some experience with being down voted. Why not learn from that experience, and post better questions. The votes and suspensions are to encourage people to post quality questions so that they're useful to future readers. This one is not useful in its current state.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that wall of code wasn't necessary;

There's a cool feature called [tabindex](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex), which manually sets the index order when you press the <kbd>tab</kbd> key. Broswers usually do that automatically, but if you see they fail at following your order, you can assign a "custom" one by declaring an explicit index on each element:

```
<input type="text" name="input1" value="" tabindex="1" />
```

Copied from the page I  linked ( w3c html specs):

> Elements that may receive focus should be navigated by user agents
>   according to the following rules:
>
> 1. Those elements that support the tabindex attribute and assign a positive value to it are navigated first. Navigation proceeds from the
>      element with the lowest tabindex value to the element with the highest
>      value. Values need not be sequential nor must they begin with any
>      particular value. Elements that have identical tabindex values should
>      be navigated in the order they appear in the character stream.
> 2. Those elements that do not support the tabindex attribute or support it and assign it a value of "0" are navigated next. These
>      elements are navigated in the order they appear in the character
>      stream.
> 3. Elements that are disabled do not participate in the tabbing order.
>
> The following elements support the tabindex attribute: A, AREA,
>   BUTTON, INPUT, OBJECT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA.

Comment: Yup, this is what he should be looking for. The problem is that the calendar has a tabindex, probably in both the button and the actual calendar so he'll have to do `tabindex=-1` to get rid of it.

Comment: Uhm, sorry @elclanrs, I have missed that; I skimmed over the code but couldn't see any reference (nor did the browser's find feature). My bad. **Update** I copy/pasted the code in an editor but still I don't understand where you saw the tabindex on both elements...I know browser's assign one order by default, with my answer I meant: "if automatic tab index order fails, give one manually"

Comment: Or it's just me who didn't understand the question, might well be

Comment: Oh, I didn't inspect the code, that's just an idea of what might be happening and how to solve it. I've had this problem before and `tabindex=-1` solves it. Good answer tho. That should put him in the right path.

Comment: Can anyone tell me in which field i may put tabindex=-1